# Drawing pictures on several different canvas elements with jQuery

Tags: ajax, html, jquery

I am trying to draw the elements returned form the ajax request on several canvas however it just draws all images to the first canvas.

***How can i access each canvas element in the success function to draw the image?***

**Jquery**

```
$(document).ready( function() {

    $('.citizen').each( function( i, citizen) {
        $.ajax({
            type : 'GET',
            url : 'getCitizenPhoto.htm',
            data : {
                socialSecurityNumber : $(citizen).val()
            },
            dataType : 'text',
            success : function(data,i) {


                var image = new Image();
                image.src = data;
                image.onload = function() {
                    var ctx = document
                    .getElementById("#photoCvs")
                    .getContext('2d');
                     ctx.drawImage( image, 0, 0, 200, 200 );

                }
            }
        });
    });
```

**HTML**

```
        <p>Victims</p>

        <c:forEach items="${victimMonitoringList}" var="victims">
        <div id="victim_row">
 <input class="citizen" id= "socialSecurityNumber" value= "${vitims.socialSecurityNumber}"/>
        <canvas id="photoCvs" class="canvas" height="200" width="200"></canvas>
        </div>  

        <div id="criminals">

        <c:forEach items="${criminalMonitoringList}" var="criminals">
        <div id="criminal_row">
     <p>Criminals</p>
    <input class="citizen" id= "socialSecurityNumber" value= "${criminal.socialSecurityNumber}"/>
        <canvas id="photoCvs" class="canvas" height="200" width="200"></canvas>
        </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Great solution for closure in loops. When you make an **ajax** call you're not able to access the index value in the call back/success function.What you want to do to avoid this scoping issue of the index used in the ajax function is to store the value of the index then make it available in the call back function.

Great solution for closure in loops. When you make an ajax call you're not able to access the index value in the call back/success function. Under is my solution to this issue:

**CODE**

Basically this did the trick - ***valueOfi***

```
$(document).ready( function() {

       $('.citizen').each( function( i, citizen) {
        $.ajax({
            type : 'GET',
            url : 'getCitizenPhoto.htm',
            valueOfi:i,
            data : {
                socialSecurityNumber : $(citizen).val()
            },
            dataType : 'text',
            success : function(data) { 
                i=this.valueOfi;
                alert(i);
                var image = new Image();
                image.src = data;
                image.onload = function() {
                var ctx = document.getElementsByClassName("canvas")[i].getContext('2d');
                ctx.drawImage( image, 0, 0, 200, 200 );

                }                   

            }
        });
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

Don't use the implicit `this` with your `.each()` callback. Instead, use the named parameter that `.each()` provides.

Also, you have *both* a `$(document).ready(function)` and a `$(function)` nested inside it. You only need one of those.

And since you're using jQuery, you don't need to use `document.getElementById()`.

I recommend a much less-heavily-nested style. When you write a `.each()` or `.ready()` call or the like, it helps to put the beginning of the callback function on the same line as the `.each`. That eliminates a level of nesting that you just don't need.

So on to your actual question. The reason all the images are going into the same canvas is that's what this code is telling it to do:

```
var ctx = document.getElementById("photoCvs").getContext('2d');
ctx.drawImage(image, 0, 0,200, 200);
```

You have multiple elements that all have `id="photoCvs"`, which isn't valid HTML. Browsers generally tolerate it, but `document.getElementById()` will just return the first one.

There are many different ways you could handle this. One, if your HTML is arranged the way you show with the canvas element as the next sibling of the `.citizen` input element, would be to use jQuery's `.next()` method.

Whatever way you do that, remove the `id="photoCvs"` from all of the canvas elements.

Putting it all together, you might end up with this:

```
$(document).ready( function() {
    $('.citizen').each( function( i, citizen ) {
        $.ajax({
            type : 'GET',
            url : 'getCitizenPhoto.htm',
            data : {
                socialSecurityNumber : $(citizen).val()
            },
            dataType : 'text',
            success : function(data) {
                var image = new Image();
                image.src = data;
                image.onload = function() {
                    var ctx = $(citizen).next()[0].getContext('2d');
                    ctx.drawImage( image, 0, 0, 200, 200 );
                }
            }
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: this still places all the pictures on one canvas i can see all the images being drawn to the same canvas

Comment: i have a canvas for each item with class name = canvas

Comment: need a way for each iteration of the ajax request to draw the image to the canvas corresponding to the index

Comment: the index 'i' isn't accessible in the success function what can be used to identify each canvas

Comment: The canvases all have the same `photoCvs` ID? That won't work too well. IDs are supposed to be unique. Can you post your HTML or JavaScript code that creates the canvases, citizen elements, etc? It's too hard to guess otherwise. BTW, that `i` variable *is* available in the success function, but I wouldn't recommend using it that way without seeing more of the code first.

Comment: maybe i can append the socialSecurityNumber to the id?